# make single plot from multi columns in matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm using quite often matplotlibs subplots and i want something like this:

```
import mumpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(8, 10), sharey='row',
                       gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 2, 2]})
ax[0, :].plot(np.random.randn(128))

ax[1, 0].plot(np.arange(128))
ax[1, 1].plot(1 / (np.arange(128) + 1))

ax[2, 0].plot(np.arange(128) ** (2))
ax[2, 1].plot(np.abs(np.arange(-64, 64)))
```

I want to create a figure that have for 2 positions a single plot like done for `ax1` in this (modified) gridspec example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure()

gs = GridSpec(3, 3)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, :])
# identical to ax1 = plt.subplot(gs.new_subplotspec((0, 0), colspan=3))
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1, :-1])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[1:, -1])
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs[-1, 0])
ax5 = plt.subplot(gs[-1, -2])

fig.suptitle("GridSpec")

plt.show()
```

see for full example: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/userdemo/demo_gridspec02.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-demo-gridspec02-py

Since i'm using the subplots environment quite a lot i would know if this is possible too. Also because subplots can handle GridSpec arguments. The pity is that it is not really explained what the exceptions are.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Get the top subplot to span 2 columns but keep the rest as they are, without using GridSpec?

Answer (score 3):

`plt.subplots` provides a convenient way to create a fully populated gridspec. 
For example, instead of

```
fig = plt.figure()
n = 3; m=3
gs = GridSpec(n, m)
axes = []
for i in range(n):
    row = []
    for j in range(m):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[i,j])
        row.append(ax)
    axes.append(row)
axes = np.array(axes)
```

you can just write a single line

```
n = 3; m=3
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=m, nrows=n)
```

However, if you want the freedom to select which positions on the grid to fill or even to have subplots spanning several rows or columns, `plt.subplots` will not help much, because it does not have any options to specify which gridspec locations to occupy. 
In that sense the documentation is pretty clear: Since it does not document any arguments that could be used to achieve a non rectilinear grid, there simply *is* no such option.

Whether to choose to use `plt.subplots` or `gridspec` is then a question of the desired plot. There might be cases where a combination of the two is still somehow useful, e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

n=3;m=3
gridspec_kw = dict(height_ratios=[3,2,1])
fig, axes  = plt.subplots(ncols=m, nrows=n, gridspec_kw=gridspec_kw)

for ax in axes[1:,2]:
    ax.remove()

gs = GridSpec(3, 3, **gridspec_kw)
fig.add_subplot(gs[1:,2])

plt.show()
```

where a usual grid is defined first and only at the positions where we need a row spanning plot, we remove the axes and create a new one using the gridspec.

[image]